# mysql functions php cli

Tags: php, mac-osx, command-line-interface, mac

I'm trying to run Symfony on my new Macbook Pro but I have no luck getting it to work with the command line scripts.

With every symfony task related to a database connection the following message appears:

```
"Couldn't locate driver named mysql"
```

So I tried testing mysql from the interactive php commandline script.
No luck there to.

```
php > mysql_connect();
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in php shell code on line 1
```

But running the mysql_connect function in the browser does work.

I already found out that php uses a different php.ini for cli scripts but I've had no luck editing that to work with the mysql commands.

Does anybody know whats wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Btw, I don't use MAMP or anything like that, just the standard php installation from osx snow leopard 5.3+ and installed mysql.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've been bashing my head against this all day.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the --php-ini flag to explicitly specify the INI file to load? I.E.

```
php --php-ini /etc/php.ini -f myfile.php
```

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't the solution. I found the cli php.ini and copied the one used for non cli to the cli php.ini but that doesn't make any difference

Comment: @frietkot Have you tried running phpinfo() from within the CLI? That will give you the 'Loaded php.ini' file (If there is one)